better_player Quality Selection in flutter
I have implemented playing youtube video using better_player package flutter. It is working fine. But the player shows only one quality option when selecting(auto option). I want to customise the quality selection and when a quality option is selected, the video must play in the selected  quality. Please help me with this issue. Thanks in advance.

better_player to play youtube video
when we select quality option, the qualities of youtube video must be changed

